# Automating RIAK start, cluster join/plan/commit in AWS EC2 [wait for riak.conf updation to complete]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation, riak

When I deploy a RIAK Node using the RIAK 2.2.0 AMI, some process is updating the `/etc/riak/riak.conf` file with the **node's actual IP address** (say 192.168.10.10 in Node1, 192.168.10.11 in Node2 and 192.168.10.12 in Node3).

Initially, `/etc/riak/riak.conf` contains a reference to IP `127.0.0.1` for all nodes; but some time later it gets updated with the node's actual IP address.

How do I know when the `/etc/riak/riak.conf` update is completed so that I can automate the **riak start, riak-admin cluster join/plan/commit** activity?

Comment: This sounds more like a server administration issue than a programming issue.  Have you tried asking on http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: I would add that the AMI isn't really meant to be used for more than playing with Riak. If your goal is to get the most out of Riak I would recommend building your own nodes.